# Pandas dataframe - find matching rows, based on IDs from two columns

Tags: python, join, merge, pandas, dataframe

I've got a dataframe, let's say it is defined like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'variable' : ["A","A","B","B","A","B","B","A"],
'id1' : [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],
'id2' : ['NaN','NaN',2,'NaN',4,3,'NaN',5]
})
```

So the result is:

```
   id1  id2 variable1
0    1  NaN         A
1    2  NaN         A
2    3    2         B
3    4  NaN         B
4    5    4         A
5    6    3         B
6    7  NaN         B
7    8    5         A
```

Now what I would like to achieve is:

1. Match rows where `id2` in one row is equal to `id1` in another row. So in this particular example, paired rows should be:

   (2, 1) - because `df.iloc[2]['id2'] == df.iloc[1]['id1']`

   and subsequently: (4, 3), (5, 2), (7, 4)
2. From these pairs, choose only those where `variable1` is constant within a pair, so from the pairs above we will have left only (5, 2) and (7, 4) because only in these cases we have:

   `df.iloc[5]['variable1'] == df.iloc[2]['variable1']`

   (example is valid for the first pair of course).

Now, if this were pure Python, I would probably iterate over two lists, containing `id1` and `id2`, checking equalities of ids and `variable`, but I suppose there should be a more array-oriented method...

Perhaps creating a duplicate dataframe and doing an intersection of `id1` and `id2` will do? Or should I consider a totally different idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
# Add index column:
df = df.reset_index()

df2 = pd.merge(
         df, df
         left_on="id1", right_on="id2"
        ).query("variable_x == variable_y")

list(df2[["index_x", "index_y"]].itertuples(index=False))
```

Comment: Thanks ;). In my defense: I was faster ;)

Answer (score 2):

maybe:

```
>>> pd.merge(df[['id2', 'variable']].reset_index(),
...          df.reset_index(), how='inner',
...          left_on=['id2', 'variable'],
...          right_on=['id1', 'variable'])[['index_x', 'index_y']]

   index_x  index_y
0        5        2
1        7        4

[2 rows x 2 columns]
```